# Install PowerShellGet module

Tags: powershell

I am working on Windows 2012 R2 and it was running PowerShell version 4.0. I have upgraded to version 5.0.

It seems like that when I do basic commands I get errors, for example,

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Install-Module –Name PowerShellGet –Force –Verbose
```

> Install-Module : The 'Install-Module' command was found in the module
>   'PowerShellGet', but the module could not be loaded. For more
>   information, run 'Import-Module PowerShellGet'. At line:1 char:1
>   + Install-Module –Name PowerShellGet –Force –Verbose
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Install-Module:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoloadMatchingModule

Another example:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> import-module PowerShellGet
```

> Get-Variable : The term 'Get-Variable' is not recognized as the name
>   of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
>   spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path
>   is correct and try again. At C:\Program
>   Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.1.3.2\PSModule.psm1:18
>   char:28
>   + $script:IsWindows = (-not (Get-Variable -Name IsWindows -ErrorAction  ...
>   +                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-Variable:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

I am basically following the installation method for PowerShellGet found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/gallery/psget/get_psget_module

I am stuck at the "Install-Module" command in this guide.

Comment: Hi Geoff, welcome to SO! Please take a moment and look into this to improve your questions and formatting: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 7):

Execute the command on your powershell: 'Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted' before executing install-module.
(The restricted mode helps you protect from the the unauthorized scripts)

Answer (score 4):

I know I too late to answer this question. But may help to others.

Try following ,

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
Set-PSRepository -Name 'PSGallery' -InstallationPolicy Trusted
```

and now you can try `install-module`

Answer (score 0):

This didn't work for me

PS C:\temp> Set-PSRepository -NAME PSGallery -InstallationPolicy Trusted
PackageManagement\Get-PackageProvider : The term 'PackageManagement\Get-PackageProvider' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\2.2.5\PSModule.psm1:2934 char:26

- ...        $nugetProvider = PackageManagement\Get-PackageProvider -ErrorA ...
- ```
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (PackageManagement\Get-PackageProvider:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PackageManagement\Get-PackageProvider : The term 'PackageManagement\Get-PackageProvider' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\2.2.5\PSModule.psm1:2948 char:40

- ... ailableNugetProviders = PackageManagement\Get-PackageProvider -Name $ ...
- ```
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (PackageManagement\Get-PackageProvider:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PackageManagement\Install-PackageProvider : The term 'PackageManagement\Install-PackageProvider' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling
of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\2.2.5\PSModule.psm1:3138 char:21

- ```
          $null = PackageManagement\Install-PackageProvider -Name $ ...
  ```
- ```
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (PackageManageme...PackageProvider:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PackageManagement\Import-PackageProvider : The term 'PackageManagement\Import-PackageProvider' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of
the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\2.2.5\PSModule.psm1:3144 char:21

- ```
          $null = PackageManagement\Import-PackageProvider -Name $s ...
  ```
- ```
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (PackageManagement\Import-PackageProvider:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PackageManagement\Get-PackageProvider : The term 'PackageManagement\Get-PackageProvider' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\2.2.5\PSModule.psm1:3148 char:30

- ...        $nugetProvider = PackageManagement\Get-PackageProvider -Name $ ...
- ```
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (PackageManagement\Get-PackageProvider:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Set-PSRepository : NuGet provider is required to interact with NuGet-based repositories. Please ensure that '2.8.5.201' or newer version of NuGet provider is installed.
At line:1 char:1

- Set-PSRepository -NAME PSGallery -InstallationPolicy Trusted
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Set-PSRepository], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotInstallNuGetProvider,Set-PSRepository
  ```

PS C:\temp>

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).